# JQuery to do list project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a To Do List Project using html css and jquery

Every time i add something  the list moves down , i don't know if it is because of css or jquery, you can see the code down below to check it, please help!!
It's always trying to be at the same level as the new list that is being added via JQuery.

Also when i did some validation so that when the user enters nothing it doesn't add it to the list, this worked for monday but all other days it didn't work even though i used the  tag in script.js

http://mohammadhalawi.6te.net/To%20Do%20List/Index.html

I uploaded it online if you want to check it out

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery MealPlaner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="todoListWrapper">
        <h1>The JQuery To Do List</h1>

        <div id="todoList" class="clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li  class="listTitle">Monday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul >
                <li class="listTitle">Tuesday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul >
                <li class="listTitle">Wednesday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul >
                <li class="listTitle">Thursday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text"  class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="listTitle">Friday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="listTitle">Saturday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" class="inputItem" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul >
                <li class="listTitle" >Sunday</li>
                <li class="addItem">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="add new item...">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="trash">
        Drop Here!
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="JQuery.js"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-color: darkgray;
}


#todoListWrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 20px 10px 30px;
    background: white;
}

.clearfix:after
{   
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;

}

#todoList ul
{
    width: 133px;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;


}

#todoList li
{
    background: none;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#todoList li:hover
{
    background: #eee;
}

#todoList li.listTitle
{
    background: #444;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;



}

#todoList li.listTitle:hover,
#todoList li.listTitle:active
{
    cursor: default;
    transform: none;
}

#todoList .emptySpace
{
    background: #fc3;
    border: dashed 1px #777;
    height: 10px;
    width: 120px;
}

#todoList li.addItem
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 111px;
    margin: 5px 4px;



}

#todoList ul:hover li.addItem
{
    display: block;
}

#todoList li.addItem input
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;


}

#todoList li.addItem :active
{
    transform: none;

}

#trash
{
    background: rgba(178,73,38,0.7);
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 35%;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;


}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function()
 {  
    $('#todoList ul').sortable({
        items: "li:not('.listTitle, .addItem')",
        connectWith:"ul",
        dropOnEmpty:true,
        placeholder: "emptySpace"
    });
    $('input').keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && $('input').val()!="")
            {   
                 var item = $(this).val();
                 $(this).parent().parent().append('<li style="font-size:13px;cursor:pointer;display:block;">'+ item + '</li>'); 
                 $(this).val("");


            }



    });

    $('#trash').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui)
        {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: do you have a copy online>? its always easier to see the example with this stuff

Comment: no but i can send you the project , plus that is all the code in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following: remove display inline-block , alter the margin and add float:left;

```
#todoList ul {
 //display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 2px;
}
```

for the second question do the following:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().trim()!="")
```

Comment: thank you that helped with the first problem but i have 1 more, i need to make sure that when a user presses enter to not add this to a list please check my script.js code , this worked for monday but the rest it's not

Comment: @MohammadHalawi See my answer.  :)

Comment: That works too.  There are too many ways to do the same thing in jQuery.  :)

Comment: better use trim so the user doesn't add space as a task

Comment: Thank you both . :)

Answer (score 0):

I just stepped through your example.  The reason that only your first input box works is because of this line:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 && $('input').val()!="")
```

`$('input')` returns an array of all the elements matching the selector, meaning all the input boxes.  When you ask for the `val()`, you'll get the value of the first input box in the array, which is `""` unless you're typing in the first input box.  So nothing happens unless you're on Monday.

You need to get the input box that you're typing into.  To do that, change your line to this:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.target.value != "")
```

`e.target` is the target of the event, which is the input box that you're typing in.